# Python: making a csv out of two lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, csv

Lets suppose that I have two lists:

```
users = [ user1, user2, user3, ...]
codes = [ code1, code2, code3, ...]
```

And I want to create a csv where I assign a code to each user like this:

```
users, codes
user1, code1
user2, code2
```

I have been trying for days and I can't find a solution. I've tried to extend the list, but it doesn't work the way it supposed to. Thanks for

Comment: Can you post what you tried and how you want the cells to look?

Comment: Use the library `pandas`.

Comment: you want to group a user with a code based on the order of the two list ?

Comment: @bboumend exactly

Comment: using zip is the way to go

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `zip` with `csv` module

**Ex:**

```
import csv    

users = [ 'user1', 'user2', 'user3']
codes = [ 'code1', 'code2', 'code3']

with open(filename, "w") as infile:
    writer = csv.writer(infile)
    writer.writerow(["users", "codes"])    #Write Header
    for i in zip(users, codes):
        writer.writerow(i)                 #Write Content
```

Answer (score 0):

that is a fairly common thing to do. Look into the module `pandas`, as @Denziloe pointed out or use `csv.writer`:

```
import csv
with open("my_csv", "w") as f:
   writer = csv.writer(f)
   writer.writerow(["user", "code"])
   for a, b in zip(users, codes):
       writer.writerow([a, b])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pandas` to store this information in a dataframe and then use `df.to_csv()`:

```
import pandas as pd

users = ['user1', 'user2', 'user3']
codes = ['code1', 'code2', 'code3']

pairs = {'Users': users, 'Codes': codes}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(pairs)

df.to_csv('mycsv.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use this code, no imports needed:

```
users = [ 'user1', 'user2', 'user3']
codes = [ 'code1', 'code2', 'code3']

with open('solution.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.write('users,codes\n')
    for user, code in zip(users, codes):
        f.write('{},{}\n'.format(user, code))
```

It will create you a file like this one:

```
users,codes
user1,code1
user2,code2
user3,code3
```

Answer (score 0):

worked for me (from https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)

```html
        users = ['user1', 'user2', 'user3']
        codes = ['code1', 'code2', 'code3']
        with open('output.csv', 'wb') as csvFile:
            fieldnames = ['USER', 'CODE']
            output = csv.DictWriter(csvFile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
            output.writeheader()
            for index, user in enumerate(users):
                output.writerow({'USER': user, 'CODE': codes[index]})
```

I got:

[image]